# How to prevent NVDA to overwrite touchscreen configurations on Windows

Tags: windows, touchscreen, accessibility

I'm using NVDA as an accessibility tool. When NVDA is on, it overwrites a set of predefined touch and gestures configurations for touchscreens, so what was before a single tap action becomes a fast double tap one. I need to prevent NVDA from overwriting some default settings on Windows (I'm using Windows 10).

I already tried removing "tap (Touch screen)" from "Input Gestures" under "Preferences" option, but it only stopped dictating, I still have to double tap to perform an action.